# Maxima: hard set colorbar's range in plot3d()

Tags: plot, colorbar, maxima

How do I hardset the colorbar's range in maxima's plot3d() ?

For instance,

```
(%i0) wxplot3d(cos(x)*cos(y),[x,-%pi,%pi],[y,-%pi,%pi]);
```

uses the default behaviour, which is a colorbar from -1 to +1, which yields

[image: Plot with default colorbar]

However, what if I want a colorbar spanning from 0 to +1 instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to do so by asking maxima to run a gnuplot `set cbrange` command before ploting

```
(%i0) wxplot3d(cos(x)*cos(y),[x,-%pi,%pi],[y,-%pi,%pi], [gnuplot_preamble, "set cbrange [0:1]"]);
```

which yields

[image: Colorbar spanning from 0 to 1, hence the saturation]